# RedBeanPHP, NotORM and DibiPHP. Which one of these simple ORM is the best?

Tags: php, database, orm, redbean, notorm

I am looking for a simple ORM for PHP for a **small** project. I found 3 of them. Do you have any idea of which one is the best?

http://redbeanphp.com

http://www.notorm.com

http://dibiphp.com

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Check out this articles - I'd read up on what types of questions to ask here - http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally picked RedBean. I never tried Notorm nor Dibiphp though, but they seem to be WAY less integrated. As an example, DibiPHP has you parse SQL queries directly.

`dibi::query('UPDATE`table`SET ', $arr, 'WHERE`id`=%i', $x);

On the other side, RedBean would not require any SQL query to run. Just create your object, set values, and send a CRUD instruction to Redbean (create, read, update, delete) :

```
$user = R::dispense( 'users' );
$user -> first_name = 'John';
$id = R::store( $user );
```